# Display Text in the Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, telerik

I have an wpf application.I want to show the selected item in the Combo box.
I get an error saying Cant use both DisplayMemberPath and Item Template.

My ItemsSource is not of string type
its a class called "StockExchange"

Following is my code :

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Column="1" DisplayMemberPath="StockExchangeName"  Name="cmbStockExchange" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="118,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="23" ItemsSource="{Binding StockExchange, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStockExchange,Mode= TwoWay}" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Summer" TabIndex="3">
                    <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <CheckBox Name="StockExchange"  Content="{Binding StockExchangeName}">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                        <Commands:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.StockExchangeCheckedCmd,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=StockExchange}" ></Commands:EventToCommand>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                        <Commands:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.StockExchangeUnCheckedCmd,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=StockExchange}" ></Commands:EventToCommand>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>                                  
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

what is solution for this? how can I display single or multiple selected Items in a Combo box?

Comment: Remove DisplayMemberPath="StockExchangeName" on RadComboBox and bind it to the Checkbox in your DataTemplate :)

Comment: It gives error saying : 
DisplayMemberPath was not found in the type checkBox

Comment: Get rid of `DisplayMemberPath`. You already have defined template for your items.

Comment: Content="{Binding StockExchangeName}" ... you did it already :)

Comment: yes but it is not showing the text.i need to click on the drop down arrow then i can see the selected item.instead i want the text to be displayed like it is shown in a text box.. r u getting what am trying to say..my english is bit weak

Answer (score 0):

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Column="1"   Name="cmbStockExchange" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="118,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="23" ItemsSource="{Binding StockExchange, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStockExchange,Mode= TwoWay}" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Summer" TabIndex="3">
                <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <CheckBox Name="StockExchange"  Content="{Binding StockExchangeName}">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                    <Commands:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.StockExchangeCheckedCmd,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=StockExchange}" ></Commands:EventToCommand>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                    <Commands:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.StockExchangeUnCheckedCmd,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=StockExchange}" ></Commands:EventToCommand>
                                </i:EventTrigger>                                  
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Create a Textblock that Shows the selected item StockExchangeName

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.StockExchangeName, ElementName=cmbStockExchange}" />
```

Comment: Where should I write this text block , bcoz if I write it inside datatemplate it is giving error.

Comment: I want to display text exactly on top of the combobox after the selection is done.so pblm is if i put it on the same position where the Combobox is then  I am unable to select the items...

Comment: the Combobox is only showing what you have defined in your datatemplate

Comment: so should i change the datatemplate?? i am not getting what r u saying..?

Comment: What is the RadComboBox showing when you select an item ?

Comment: I shows me the drop down with the selected items list.

Comment: this is what you want right ? so you have to customize your datatemplate to let the RadComboBox Display what you want. I cant help anymore because i dont have the Telerik Controls here

Answer (score 0):

If you select CheckBox, no item is shown selected in comboBox because no item is selected since click event is handled by checkbox.

You can ***bind IsChecked with IsSelected value of ComboBoxItem*** so that on click of checkbox corresponding item gets selected.

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding StockExchangeName}"
            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}}"/>
```

This will show checkBox in comboBox because you have provided template with checkBox in it for comboBoxItem.